# Xamarin.Forms: GroupHeaderTemplate {Binding Key } is not working, But ItemTemplate {Binding Key} works well

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a mobileApp with Xamarin forms. My problem is that I cannot get GroupHeader. I checked all platforms and websites. I couldn't find any solution for my problem. My fist listview works well and at second listview I want to show my values with groupheaders. My .xaml and .cs codes and scroonshots are below. I successfully got my all values from web service. And My values are shown at second listview except group headers.

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedList}"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" Margin="0,0,0,15">

                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Height="50" >
                            <Label Text ="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Gray" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ViewCell>
                            

                            <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,0,0,1" >

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.4*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label  Text="{Binding PayDeskName}"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Gray"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CollectionType}"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Blue"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CollectionAmount, StringFormat='{0:N}'}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"></Label>


                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

--

```
using MunIS.Parameters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;


namespace MunIS.AccrumentCollection
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CollectionPage : ContentPage
{
    public CollectionPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public PayDeskBaseCollectionParameters[] CollectionList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, PayDeskBaseCollectionParameters>> GroupedList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, PayDeskBaseCollectionParameters>> CollectionTypeBasedGroupedList { get; set; }

    async void GetCollectionList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activityStackLayout.IsVisible = true;
        activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        loadingTxt.IsVisible = true;

        string queryIntervalStartDate = dtIntervalStart.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
        string queryIntervalFinishDate = dtIntervalFinish.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
        CollectionDetailQueryCriteriaParameters criteria = new CollectionDetailQueryCriteriaParameters();
        criteria.CollectionDateStart = dtIntervalStart.Date;
        criteria.CollectionDateFinish = dtIntervalFinish.Date;

        ServiceCaller serviceCaller = new ServiceCaller();
        CollectionList = await serviceCaller.ListPayDeskBasedCollections(criteria);



        var groupedCollectionList = CollectionList.GroupBy(c => c.CollectionType).Select(
        g => new
        {
            CollectionType = g.Key,
            CollectionAmount = g.Sum(s => s.CollectionAmount)
        });




        GroupedList = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, PayDeskBaseCollectionParameters>>(CollectionList.GroupBy(c => c.PayDeskName)
            .Select(k => new Grouping<string, PayDeskBaseCollectionParameters>(k.Key + "\t\t" + CollectionList
            .Where(c => c.PayDeskName == k.Key)
            .Sum(x => x.CollectionAmount).ToString("N"), k)));


        listview1.ItemsSource = groupedCollectionList;
        listview.ItemsSource = GroupedList;



        activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        loadingTxt.IsVisible = false;
        activityStackLayout.IsVisible = false;




    }
}
}
```

And this is my Grouping.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MunIS
{
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[See my Page I want to get groupheaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD5vH.png)

Comment: Your label text color of the group template is Gray, change to some different color, since your header background color is also gray

Comment: Hi @HimanshuDwivedi , it's not about color. I changed it and the problem is still same.

Answer (score 2):

[This worked for me](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/02/xamarin-vs2022-member-not-found-in.html)

remove the x:DataType attribute from the XAML. For some reason doing this for the overall page creates problems with templated controls that have their own context.

And as Jeroen Corteville said, you need to remove the GroupDisplayBinding aswell. The two do the same, but somehow works differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove GroupDisplayBinding from your listview element.

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" 
                      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedList}"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" Margin="0,0,0,15">
```

> This property is mutually exclusive with GroupHeaderTemplate property.
> Setting it will set GroupHeaderTemplate to null.

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.groupdisplaybinding?view=xamarin-forms#remarks